# Как получить данные CharField модели?

Tags: django

Как получить данные переменной модели из базы данных? Модель имеет СharField. Надо получить данные этого поля модели с определенным id из базыданных.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим ваша модель называется Album.
И если пишите код используя классы:

views.py

```
pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
current_album = Album.objects.get(id=pk)
current_album.ваше_поле_СharField
```

urls.py cледует указать например:

```
path("get/album/<int:pk>/",AlbumView.as_view())
```

Пример из учебного проекта.

```
class PickUpAlbumView(View):
    """забрать альбом"""
    def get_object(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        try:
            return Album.objects.get(id=pk)
        except Album.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        album = self.get_object(pk)
        album.user.add(request.user)

        return redirect('profile')
```

Comment: немного не понятно в данном примере откуда у вас `self` прилетает. Дайте объяснение, плз

Comment: self идет как первый аргумент если ты используешь классы https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why

Comment: Вот теперь понятно, что вы используете логику для получения в классе модели. Т.к. `.objects.get(pk=...)` можно применить во`views.py` и обойтись без обращения к `self` во `views.py`. Наприер так, `PickUpAlbumView.objects.get(pk=...)`, но подход с определением логики геттеров и сеттеров в классе модели на мой взгляд правильнее. Хотя в учебных материалах это не с первых строк можно найти и понять

Comment: Рад, что мой ответ оказался полезен.

Comment: надеюсь для ТС так и есть, но уберите `self` во `views.py`. Я так и не понял на какой объект ссылается там `self`. Или дайте пояснение для `views.py`. С классом все топ.

Comment: Мне нравится вот такое обьяснение self:  
dog‎: у котов внутри есть мурчалка
dog‎: она реализована для всех котов в классе кот
‎dog‎: в объекте кот надо как то вызвать метод мурчало у класса кот
‎dog‎: как ты это сделаешь?
dog‎: кот.мурчало()
‎dog‎: ежели ты вызовешь кот.мурчало(), муркнут сразу все коты на свете
‎dog‎: а ежели ты вызовешь self.мурчало(), муркнет только тот кот, на которого указывает self

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу раз такое дело. Вы имеете модель допустим такую. `pk` при данном примере формируются [автоматически](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key), т.е. если вы не опредeлили, то поле добавится автоматически:

```py
#models.py

class ConfigNew(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Из `views.py` вы можете обратиться на прямую при помощи такого запроса:

```py
from app.models import ConfigNew

def any_func(request):
    id = 53 # это для примера значение, можете передавать сюда как хотите
    config = ConfigNew.objects.get(pk=id)
    context = {"config":config}
    return render(request, "any.html", context)
```

Вот в принципе и все, переменная `config` содержит объект класса `ConfigNew()` с определенным вами `id`. В `any.html` вы можете увидеть, что содержит ваш `config`, вызвав вот так `{{config}}`

Но одно "но", хотя приведенный выше пример вполне рабочий я стараюсь его так не использовать, а писать функции в самом классе. Т.е. переносить логику из `views.py`, пользоваться только функциями